# C#: How can I use reflection in order to cast an object?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public static void myMethod(Object myObject)
{

}
```

My object is of type SportCar. How can I create a new Object (Something like this)

```
SportCart sportCar = myObject as SportCar
```

Later Edit: I don't know what is the type of myObject. It could be SimpleCar, AbcCar etc

Comment: Have you tried running that line? (Also `as` is not part of reflection I think, and you should not use reflection if it isn't 100% necessary.)

Comment: Are you trying to create a new object of the same (unknown) type, or are you trying to cast myObject to a SportCar (because you know that's what it is)?

Comment: I don't know what is the type of myObject. It could be SimpleCar, AbcCar etc

Comment: Could you post some sample code, so as for us to see the purpose of the cast/conversion

Comment: if you don't know the actual type why do you need to cast it in the first place? How do you want to work with a concrete type variable if you don't know the type? Give a better description of your problem - it seems you're actually trying to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally where you would use an interface. In your case, `myMethod` must be doing something specific with the argument passed in. Lets take a simple example; say `myMethod` was responsible for starting the car, you would define an interface such as

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Start()
}
```

Then the argument to `myMethod` would be of type `ICar` rather than `object`.

```
public void myMethod(ICar car)
{
   car.Start();
}
```

Now `mymethod` does not need to know (or care!!) what `ICar` is presented, be it AbcCar, SportsCar etc. as long as that class implements `ICar`

```
public class SportsCar : ICar
{
   public void Start() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Vroom Vroom. SportsCar has started");
   }
}

public class AbcCar : ICar
{
   public void Start() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Chug Chug. AbcCar has started");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want one of two things. Either have a base class `Car` or interface ICar that has all the shared behaviour that cars have and then you can do:

```
ICar car = myObjectAsCar;
car.Drive(Speed.VeryFast);
```

Or, you want to do different things, depending on what type of car it is:

```
if (SportCar sporty = myObject as SportCar)
{
     sporty.Drive(Speed.VeryFast);
}
if (HybridCar hybrid = myObject as HybridCar)
{
     hybrid.Drive(Speed.Economical);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the car classes have a common type, and you just want to cast to that i.e.:

```
BaseCar baseCar = myObject as BaseCar;
```

Or are you trying to examine the type first and then cast to the correct type, i.e.:

```
if(myObject is SimpleCar)
{
  var simpleCar = myObject as SimpleCar;
}
```

If you're thinking of doing the second, I strongly recommend you use the first. And if you're using the first you don't need to worry about what type of car it is.